# Oracle sequences: CURRVAL not allowed here?

Tags: oracle, sequence

The following Oracle SQL code generates the error "***ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here***":

```
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID,Name) VALUES (Customer_Seq.nextval,'AAA');
SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID=Customer_Seq.currval;
```

The error occurs on the second line (SELECT statement). I don't really understand the problem, because this does work:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID,Name) VALUES (Customer_Seq.nextval,'AAA');
SELECT Customer_Seq.currval from dual;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have posted some sample code, so it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to know the assigned value, say for passing to some other procedure you could do something like this:

```
SQL> var dno number
SQL> insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc)
  2      values (deptno_seq.nextval, 'IT', 'LONDON')
  3      returning deptno into :dno
  4  /

1 row created.

SQL> select * from dept
  2  where deptno = :dno
  3  /

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        55 IT             LONDON

SQL>
```

**Edit**

We can use the RETURNING clause to get the values of any column, including those which have been set with default values or by trigger code.

Comment: I want to retrieve the record just created, including the generated sequence and any defaults that were set on columns.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what version of Oracle you are using.  There have in the past been limitations on where sequences can be used in PL/SQL - mostly if not all gone in 11G.  Also, there are restrictions in SQL - see [this list](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287).

In this case you may need to write:

```
SELECT Customer_Seq.currval INTO v_id FROM DUAL; 
SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID=v_id;
```

(Edited after comments).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really directly answer your question, but maybe what you want to do can be resolved using a the INSERT's RETURNING clause?

```
DECLARE
  -- ...
  last_rowid rowid;
  -- ...
BEGIN
  -- ...
  INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID,Name) VALUES (Customer_Seq.nextval,'AAA') RETURNING rowid INTO last_rowid;
  SELECT * FROM Customer where rowid = last_rowid;
  -- ...
END;
/
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but when your code is executed, I get "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: There is no need for the select statement, really. You can get all the data you need from the returning clause of the insert statement.

Comment: Actually there **is** a need for the select statement in my application. I need a generic solution to return a complete record that was inserted. For now, I've solved it by returning the "sequenced" columns by using "returning" and running a separate select statement afterwards. Not ideal, but it does the job.

Answer (score 3):

You may not use a sequence in a WHERE clause - it does look natural in your context, but Oracle does not allow the reference in a comparison expression.

[Edit]

This would be a PL/SQL implementation:

```
declare
v_custID number;
cursor custCur is
  select customerid, name from customer
   where customerid = v_custID;
begin
select customer_seq.nextval into v_custID from dual;
insert into customer (customerid, name) values (v_custID, 'AAA');
commit;
for custRow in custCur loop
 dbms_output.put_line(custRow.customerID||' '|| custRow.name); 
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: So what is the solution then?

Comment: It depends -  are you using this within a PL/SQL block?  The general idea would be to save the sequence value once you have it from the first operation and apply it through a bind variable in the second query.

Answer (score -2):

You have not created any

```
sequence
```

First create any sequence its cycle and cache. This is some basic example

```
Create Sequence seqtest1
Start With 0             -- This Is Hirarchy Starts With 0
Increment by 1           --Increments by 1
Minvalue 0               --With Minimum value 0
Maxvalue 5               --Maximum Value 5. So The Cycle Of Creation Is Between 0-5
Nocycle                  -- No Cycle Means After 0-5 the Insertion Stopes
Nocache   --The cache Option Specifies How Many Sequence Values Will Be Stored In Memory For Faster Access
```

You cannot do Where Clause on Sequence in SQL beacuse you cannot filter a sequence . Use procedures like @APC said