# Using SEQUENCE(Oracle) in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle sequences: CURRVAL not allowed here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438454/oracle-sequences-currval-not-allowed-here)

In my program i am inserting a values using sequence.

Procedure 1

```
Insert tablename(id,name) values(seq.nextval,somename)
```

now i need to update this same table. how do i do it. I use another Procedure to update.

Procedure 2

```
Update set name ='someothername'
where id = seq.currval
```

but i get an error that i cannot use sequence in where clause. 
How do i rewrite my update condition so as to use my current sequence value to update.